# How to Toggle A Movieclip to appear on a Button's Mousehover HTML Canvas

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, canvas

I am using Animate CC 2017 and Canvas as my document. I have an animated button and a Movieclip. I want to know How to Toggle the Movieclip to appear on my Animated button's mousehover.

Button Instance Name is : `button_1`

Clip Instance name is : `injector`

I have only one keyframe on my animated screen.

Below is the code what I am doing

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.button_1.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{
    if (injector.alpha == 0)
    {
        injector.alpha = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        injector.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

So this condition is not working but alert working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check for javascript errors in the console?
If not, I suspect it's because 'injector' is not in scope. Try this:

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.button_1.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

var ref = this;

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{
    if (ref.injector.alpha == 0)
    {
        ref.injector.alpha = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        ref.injector.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Working Like a Charm!